# Jetpack Compose Tutorial In google developers compose class incorrect code

Tags: android

I am trying to learn compose google android studio developers course. The code from the class is incorrect in android studio, I don't know how to fix it, I am a complete noob and just trying to learn
I had to post images because it kept giving me code format errors.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mp4vz.png)

> this is pasted direct from the course and it comes up with these errors
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvBSb.png)

I tried searching composable invocations but I don't understand the fixes I'm still new to all of this.

Comment: Please post code and errors here as text, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not familiar with Kotlin. BasicCodeLabTheme has lambda function inside constructor. That lambda has signature

```
function: () -> Unit
```

So you can pass only lambda which obtain nothing(no one parameter) and return Unit.

MyApp is Composable function, so you can invoke MyApp function only from Composable function. You are trying to pass Composable lamdba.

```
{ MyApp(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) }
```

Which has signature

```
function: @Composable () -> Unit
```

Just change

```
BasicCodeLabTheme(function: () -> Unit) {}
```

To

```
BasicCodeLabTheme(function: @Composable () -> Unit) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can start from here written in Kotlin.
https://medium.com/p/cb42e1d021cf
A beginner's guide for jetpack composes a vertical list. I hope it helps.